# How can I bind from a user control to an external object in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an image inside a user control that I want to bind it's visibility to a property I have set up in a class object.  The dependency properties are set up and working correctly, but I don't know how to set the binding properly on the image.

The user control and class object are in the same namespace.  I thought I would need to set the `ElementName` to the window or the `RelativeSource` to the class object, but I'm not getting it to work out.

Here's what a dependency property looks like (defined in `MigrateUserWizardObject.cs`, this inherits from `DependencyObject`, this resides in the `UserAccountMigrator` namespace):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DatabaseStepCompletedVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DatabaseStepCompletedVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MigrateUserWizardObject));

public Visibility DatabaseStepCompletedVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return (Visibility)GetValue(DatabaseStepCompletedVisibilityProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(DatabaseStepCompletedVisibilityProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Here's an image that I want bound to this dependency property (defined in `ProgressUserControl.xaml`, this inherits from `UserControl`, this resides in the `UserAccountMigrator` namespace as well):

```
<Image x:Name="DatabaseCompleted" Source="{StaticResource GreenCheckMarkSource}" Visibility="{Binding Path=DatabaseStepCompletedVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image>
```

This is due to the fact that the `DataContext` of the image is the user control.  How can I make this work?

Comment: Could you show the full markup? It's difficult to understand from your description.

Comment: Sure. I was hoping it was going to be a simple answer, as I'm just new to binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern.  Instead of setting the DataContext to the UserControl, set it to an instance of another class (ProgressViewModel, for example).  This view model would have all the properties you want to bind to (including your DatabaseStepCompletedVisibility property) and makes it much easier.  Right now you are wanting to bind some things to the UserControl, some things to another object somewhere else, etc.. and, as you have found, makes it difficult.  Here is more information:

http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/432/MVVM-for-Tarded-Folks-Like-Me-or-MVVM-and-What-it-Means-to-Me.aspx

Without going that approach, you have to have an instance MigrateUserWizardObject to bind to.  You can put that instance in your UserControl (if you insist on using it as the DataContext), then you can bind the the property of the MigrateUserWizardObject property of the UserControl.  Also, your MigrateUserWizardObject doesn't have to be a dependency object or dependency property to bind to.  A better pattern would be to make it a plain c# class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thank you for the simple and helpful article!  Following MVVM was much simpler than what I was initially doing.